# How can I use a Verbatim Secure'n'Go USB key?

Tags: partitioning, security, compatibility, usb-drive

I have purchased a 4Gb USB key from Verbatim.

How can I use it under Ubuntu? I do not need the "secure data" feature, and have still not saved anything on it, so formatting at low level would be OK.

However, I was not able to do it, although I tried several things.

Some details:
 The Key comes with a windows-only application which (under Windows) forces you to set a (non empty) password before the first use. Then , every time you insert the key, it asks for the password to grant access. The key actually has two partitions, the smaller one (41Mb) containing the auto-executable software and doc, and the bigger one (the actual storage space) being initially empty.

In Ubuntu, I can only see the small partition with ls or a file manager.

However, "`ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/*usb*`" outputs:

```
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Verbatim_Secure_Data_USB_070007013AA6EDB2DE98-0:0 -> ../../sdb
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Verbatim_Secure_Data_USB_070007013AA6EDB2DE98-0:1 -> ../../sr1
```

Surprisingly, "`sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdb`" says:

```
/dev/sdb: No medium found
```

and "`sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sr1`" says:

```
mkfs.vfat: unable to open /dev/sr1: Read-only file system
```

Indeed, `/dev/sr1` is marked `brw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 11`
 ... which could explain why the system is read-only!

Finally, I do not see any of the two partitions in gparted or with "`sudo fdisk -l`"

Thanks for your help!

Bernoot